# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy to allow public internet traffic but deny private network traffic

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I was able to apply a NetworkPolicy that successfully allows all egress and ingress traffic:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: test-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  egress:
  - {}
  ingress:
  - {}
```

When I applied the following NetworkPolicy I was unable to have the pod be able to return a public website's HTML back to me:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: test-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  egress:
  - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
        podSelector:
         matchLabels:
            k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
      - port: 53
        protocol: UDP
      - port: 53
        protocol: TCP
  - to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: ::/0
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 80
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 443
  ingress:
  - {}
```

Ultimately what I want to do is allow the pod to contact any public internet website but block it from accessing anything on our private network. The second NetworkPolicy listed here is just my attempt to introduce a rule beyond the first allow all policy.